# android pattern lock blocks internet access?

Tags: android

My app transfers data to an internet server at regular intervals. It does this ok when locked  with my phone which has the standard lock - no pin or pattern.   I am testing with a friends phone which has a pattern lock and it seems that when locked with a pattern it does not have internet access.   Is my suspicion correct?   If so could someone point me towards a method to establish the internet connection even tho pattern locked?

Comment: are you sure it is connected to the pattern lock? Did you try to remove the lock on the friends' phone? Couldn't it be the wifi setting for instance, that can  be shut down when locked?

Comment: On my own phone the wifi stays enabled when locked - is there a user option to shut down wifi when locking?

Comment: There is an option tied to the screen being on or of I think